# Internet very slow on Ubuntu, but not on Windows

Tags: 12.04, internet-connection, download-speed

I have a 10mb of connection speed, on Windows the download speed is around 1200kbps.

But in Ubuntu it is always around 150kbps, its very slow than expected.

I tried to solve this by changing the server in software channels setting to best server, but this does not work for me.

Same speed on Chrome downloads.

I really hope that you guys can help me with this, because its really bad.

Comment: So it's not just apt, it's the whole system. Is your connection a wifi/wireless? Are you sure no-one else is using your connection or "borrowing" internet access from you? Try using ethernet, see if it works with a wired/ethernet connection.

Comment: Its a wired connection. Nobody is using the connection, just me. On Windows 7 its working fine, the problem is just with Linux distributions.

Comment: While using ubuntu, if you go to http://speedtest.net you get less bandwidth? Do the same while on windows, just to see if there is a countable difference on the same server. Also, provide the output of `sudo lshw -C network` in your question.

Comment: This question has been untouched since last July it should therefor be closed as too localized. It might not help future visitors if there were no solution or if the problem were localized.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the MTU.

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run this command:

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

Comment: Would you please be so kind to add information about how this will solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Sadly this could be due to the driver, most work perfectly and some even better than Windows' own but their are the odd few that aren't as good or fast as the MS driver and seem to run slower, Atheros are the main culprits...  What you could do it try the newer 12.10 release when it is available and see if the new kernel comes with an improved driver for your device...

Answer (score -2):

try installing the wicd instead the network-manager, described here http://www.techdrivein.com/2012/09/slow-erratic-wifi-ubuntu1204-fixed.html

Comment: This is a good point, but can you please summarize the steps to install wicd in your answer in case the page you link to ever disappears?